# Users image in my site programatically

Tags: web-part, user-profile

How to get the users image in my site programatically?

I need to show image of the logged-in user in my webpart.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function below will get you the UserProfile based on the accountName

```
public static UserProfile GetUserInfo(string AccountName)
{
    UserProfile profile = null;
    SPServiceContext serviceContext = SPServiceContext.Current;
    UserProfileManager profileManager = new UserProfileManager(serviceContext);
    if (AccountName != string.Empty)
    {
        profile = profileManager.GetUserProfile(AccountName);
    }
    else
    {
        profile = profileManager.GetUserProfile(SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.RawSid);
    }
    return profile;
}
```

The picture URL will be in

```
userProfile[PropertyConstants.PictureUrl];
```

Comment: Can I set Picture of User Profile without configuring mySite ?

Answer (score 0):

```
  SPFieldUrlValue fieldUrl = new SPFieldUrlValue(item["Links"].ToString());
  url = fieldUrl.Url;
  string[] splittedValues = url.Split('=');
  string accountName =splittedValues[1].ToString();
  accountName.Replace("%5C","\\");

  ServerContext ServerContext = ServerContext.GetContext(site);
  UserProfileManager profileManager = new UserProfileManager(ServerContext);
  UserProfile spUser = profileManager.GetUserProfile(accountName);
  IDictionaryEnumerator userProperties = spUser.GetEnumerator();

  string picture = spUser["PictureURL"].Value.ToString();
  row["Links"] = url;
  row["URL"] = picture;
```

Comment: Do you always have the user account on the url? Why split strings? If you want info on current user, wouldn't it be cheaper to just get user info from SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser?