# How can we display the email-id and profile picture of loggedin user on a webpart?

Tags: ssom

In SharePoint 2013, using SSOM, we need to display the email-id and profile picture of loggedin user on a webpart?

What is best practice? Do I need to use SPContext.Current.User or Do I use the userprofile properties?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use `SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb.CurrentUser.Email` for Email. For profile picture on you will have to get it from userprofile properties. (You can refer this [Users image in my site programatically](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/20680/users-image-in-my-site-programatically))